# How to call a macro on a button click in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to macro programming in VB, and what I'm trying to do is clone a row in my word document when a button is clicked. I've made an attempt as shown in the picture below. What do I need to do to make the addTwoDependants() subroutine run when the button is clicked?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public sub cloneDependants_Click()
   call addTwoDependants
end sub
```

Your code should work as well.
Are you getting any error? If so, post a comment to this answer or edit your question to mention that.

EDIT: Looking at the screenshot, you have added the code for `addTwoDependants` under a document named Normal. To fix this, add a module under the document which has the button (Fna) and move the above code in the newly added bas module.

Comment: Compile Error: Sub or function not defined.